# What is the equivalent of this line of code for Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, pageviews

I'm searching the equivalent of this line of code from the old Google Analytics for Universal Analytics :

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
```

should do it

See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages?hl=de)